# Why does my LOG.error print my array? Liferay

Tags: java, json, ajax, liferay

Why does my log.error print my JSON array?

This is my code:

```
if(strResourceId.equalsIgnoreCase("transactionTypes")){         
    long transactionID = ParamUtil.getLong(resourceRequest, "paramTran");
    TransactionTypeFacade transTypeFacade = TransactionTypeFacade.getInstance();
    JSONArray transTypes = transTypeFacade.findTransTypes_By_TransId(transactionID);
    LOG.error(transTypes);
    objWriteJSON.writeJsonToResponse(resourceResponse, transTypes.toString());
}
```

And my console output:

```
22:28:25,674 ERROR 
[http-bio-8080-exec-113]
[IncidentsPortlet:276] 
[{"id":6,"name":"Cambio de Equipo"},{"id":5,"name":"Cambio de Plan"},
{"id":3,"name":"Cortes por Robo"},
{"id":9,"name":"Otros"},
{"id":2,"name":"Recargas Viirtuales"},
{"id":7,"name":"Reclamaciones"},
{"id":1,"name":"Supercargas"},
{"id":8,"name":"Superchip"},
{"id":4,"name":"Venta Prepago"}]
```

Comment: What did you expect? You are calling to `LOG.error(transTypes);` and `transTypes` is a `JSONArray`

Comment: You have printed an array and so that is what it is showing,are you looking for some specific values as such?